# GFCI in kitchen

Tags: electrical, kitchens, gfci

I have a double gang in my kitchen. I dont know where the wires come from but one lead to the old plug and another to a switch (which I believe is set up for 3 way).
I am now replacing the old plug with a GfCI since it is close to the sink but am not successfully wiring it. For the plug I have red, black, white, ground. And same for the switch
I put black white and ground to my GfCI and capped off red. I also put red white ground and capped off black and i just get a red light on my gfci and it wont reset to green.
As for the switch beside it i wired:
Top left: white
Top right: black
Bottom right: red
And ground.
Id link a picture but it says file size too large.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks[image]

Comment: Pictures would help a lot. I set up a system (I don't make any money off this, and the pictures delete from my server after an hour) at http://www.picturepdf.com/shrink/ - you email the picture to shrink@PicturePDF.com and it will send back a small-enough-for-stack-exchange picture that you can upload directly or via link.

Comment: Added the best pic i could. Thanks for the link

Comment: Do you still have the old receptacle that you can examine? I'm wondering if the old one had tab broke off. I had to do it on mine with switch connected. Also, maybe look into GFCI/AFCI breaker.

Comment: On 3-way switches, position means *nothing*.  Every 3-way puts the screws in different positions.  You need to look at screw color.   Unfortunately you've really dug yourself a hole here, by tearing everything off at once and expecting wire colors to save you.  Wire colors mean *less than nothing* in 3-way circuits, that knowledge is stored in "how the old switch was connected". Yeah, they're a real pain.

Comment: I know how the old wiring was done i can draw a diagram if you guys want…

Comment: @AntonioMezzapelle -- a diagram would be quite useful, yes

Answer (score 1):

For the duplex receptacle: With black/red/white you likely had either: *1/2 switched* or *MWBC split*. Either way, you would have had hot (but not neutral) tab removed.

The problem is that a standard duplex GFCI receptacle doesn't have that "split" capability. So we need to first figure out what is going on:

- With the breaker off, open up (uncap) the black, red and white wires and spread them apart to be safe/separate from each other and from all other wires and from the metal box.
- Turn the breaker on.
- Using a multimeter, carefully measure voltage between black & white, between red & white and between black & red.
- Turn the breaker off.

You should get one of two possibilities:

- black & white = 120V, red & white = 120V, black & red = 0V - This is a split circuit, normally to have a switch for one of the receptacles. If this is the case, you need to figure out which switch (next to this, across the room, etc.) controlled which receptacle in order to figure out what to do next.
- black & white = 120V, red & white = 120V, black & red = 240V - This is a MultiWire Branch Circuit (MWBC). In this case, you can only use 1/2 the circuit here, but that's OK. Simple fix is indeed to cap one of the hots (black or red) and install the other hot, neutral (white) and ground as normal.

In addition, you need to make sure that you are **only using the LINE side** of the GFCI. On a regular receptacle, you have top and bottom are the same, with hot on one side and neutral on the other. A GFCI is a totally different setup, with typically one side for hot & neutral but with LINE on the top and LOAD on the bottom. If you have only one cable connecting to a receptacle then you will *not* use the LOAD screws at all.

Comment: I dont have a multi meter but i can go purchase one. I only have a current tester and the little plug in thing that tells you if you have correct wiring. I tried capping black and using red then capping red and using black, only using the line part of the gfci (the top screws left and right) gfci shows a red light and wont reset. Im assuming this means the solution lies in your option #1. I need to find what switch the wires come from. What do i do then?

Comment: By the way, i know this is really dumb but i put black on line and red on load and i switched on the gfci and there was a big POW and the breaker tripped. Maybe this means that between black and red there is 240v?

Comment: It might. But it could be something else. But that may be a clue: Was the breaker a single or double breaker? Upload a picture of the panel showing the breaker - that may be useful here.

Comment: Its a single breaker

Comment: Right now i put a regular plug with black top right white bottom left and ground. My tester says wiring is correct. However, when i test the other wires (the ones that should go to the switch) i have no power in black or red

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the help.
I ended up using a multimeter and discovering that only one of the two sets of wires carried power so i used that for the gfci than carried the rest of the power over to the switch with the second 120V wire. It all works